# multiple dataframe columns to list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

input is df:

```
   A  B
0  a  d  
1  b  e
2  c  f
```

the output is a text file each row of df in a new line:

df.txt

```
a, d
b, e
c, f
```

I can make it in an ugly way, what's the most efficient and pretty way of doing this?

Comment: `df.to_csv('df.txt', sep=',', header=None, index=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try like this way to make it comma separated without `header` using [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv)?

```
df.to_csv('df.txt', index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: so, the comma is by default it seems

Comment: @LeonRai Yes it is comma `sep=','` by default